# I have an sfd file for a new written script. How do i install it on windows such that I get to use it on Microsoft Word?

Tags: fonts, ms-word

I'm working a new script(like Indic or Latin scripts) called Bharathi,which can be used to write any Indian language. I have this script font in an sfd file. But Windows does not recognise sfd as a format.Is there some software I need to install for this?

Answer (score 2):

- SFD is the font format of the [Fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) software
- Fontforge can convert to other font formats
- ... and is free